# 256 AES Encryption C# .Net Core not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption

I have a couple of projects in different languages that encrypt/decrypt string, for example, a php project can encrypt a string and store in a database and a c# project should be able to pull it out of the database and decrypt it.

I have a c# .net core project which I've successfully made the decryption method to decrypt string that are encrypted from other projects, but I now need a method that also does the encryption.

I have implemented a method which isn't throwing any errors but the encryption string it returns is completely wrong.

Below is my implementation of the encryption

```
public string encrypt(string decryptedString)
{
    string encrypted;
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CipherKey);
    System.Security.Cryptography.Aes aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CipherIv);
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform decipher = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(cs))
            {
                sr.Write(decryptedString);

                var encryptedString = ms.ToArray();
                var result = new byte[aes.IV.Length + encryptedString.Length];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(aes.IV, 0, result, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedString, 0, result, aes.IV.Length, encryptedString.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

And the equivalent method to decrypt (the decryption works fine) is below

```
public string decrypt(string encryptedPassword, bool throwException = false)
{
    try
    {
        string decrypted;
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CipherKey);
        System.Security.Cryptography.Aes aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
        aes.KeySize = 256;   
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CipherIv);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] base64decodeBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPassword);
        string base64Decode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64decodeBytes);
        
        ICryptoTransform decipher = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(base64decodeBytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                {
                    decrypted = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            
            return decrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return encryptedPassword;
        }
   }
```

**UPDATE**

From the advice in the comment by 500 - Internal Server Error I have made a change which seems to have resolved the issue somewhat but I am now getting junk at the start of the string in the decryption.

For example I am doing the following to test:

```
string encryptionString = encryption.encrypt("Hello World");
Console.WriteLine("Encrypted String: {0}", encryptionString);

string decodedString = encryption.decrypt(encryptionString);
Console.WriteLine("Decrypted String: {0}", decodedString);
```

> Encrypted String: Z3BmenhibnNmZ1tqa2xhZgs/GYMu49dNPNGoRROTWz4=
> Decrypted String: �u�D'���);�
> SKHHello World

Comment: Maybe try moving `var encryptedString = ms.ToArray();` and what follows outside the `using (CryptoStream...` block - I have a feeling the output hasn't been flushed yet where you do it now.

Comment: Should have thought of that, it sort of working, except I am getting junk in the decryption. I have a test where I encrypt the string "Hello World" and then decrypt the result but I get some junk as follows:

Encrypted String: Z3BmenhibnNmZ1tqa2xhZgs/GYMu49dNPNGoRROTWz4=
Decrypted String: �u�D'���);�
                             SKHHello World

Comment: You are prepending IV to the encrypted string, then don't use it anywhere (you should have cut it off and feed as IV before decrypting, instead of using the same hardcoded IV every time), so you decrypt is as that junk.

Comment: @Evk Good catch. I found that on some tutorial I thought it was a little odd, I've changed the byte array to just be the length of the encrypted string and do the same for the CopyBlock and now its working as expected. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: That's actually correct implementation because IV should be random for every encryption, not the same hardcoded IV you use now. Then it's usually prepended to encrypted string and extracted from it for decryption.